# How to add seconds and hours in Stored procedure sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio 2008.  I am trying to get information from database.  There are the example of linq query

```
    var fbPost = db.FacebookStatusUpdates
                .Where(f => f.Status == FacebookNotificationStatus.Active &&
                            f.Alarm.User.FbStatus == true)
                .AsEnumerable() 
                .Where(f => f.FacebookUpdateTime - f.ClientTime.Offset <=
                            DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime.AddSeconds(f.Offset))
                                .ToList();
```

There is my stored procedure:

```
 declare @date2 datetimeoffset=getutcDate();
 select a.*
 from [Alllarm].[dbo].[FacebookStatusUpdates] a
 inner join [Alllarm].[dbo].[Alarms] b
 inner join [Alllarm].[dbo].[Users] o
  on o.[Id] = b.[User_id] on b.Id=a.[Alarm_id]
 where o.[FbStatus] = 1 and a.Status=2
 and   DATEADD(hour,datepart(tz,a.ClientTime),a.FacebookUpdateTime)<=DATEADD(second, a.Offset,    @date2);
```

Thare is my model:

```
    public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FacebookID { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }
    public bool? FbStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Alarm> Alarms { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Sms> Sms { get; set; }
}

public class Alarm
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int Snoozes { get; set; }
    public bool Repeat { get; set; }
    public DateTime AlarmUpdateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FacebookNotificationStatus> StatusUpdates { get; set; }
}

public class FacebookStatusUpdate
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FacebookUpdateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FacebookPostTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ClientTime { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    public virtual FacebookNotificationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Alarm Alarm { get; set; }
}
```

But when I ran a stored procedure nothing heppend.  I think that I miss something in that line

```
and   DATEADD(hour,datepart(tz,a.ClientTime),a.FacebookUpdateTime)<=DATEADD(second, a.Offset,    @date2);
```

Can somebody help me ?

a.ClientTime has type DateTimeOffset 2013-11-13 12:03:36.0000000 +02:00
a.Offset  type int (seconds)

Comment: Look into DATEDIFF(...)

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has a [DATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289(v=sql.100).aspx) type, equivalent to .NET's [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) . By changing your table types to it you avoid conversions and can query with simple comparison operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probem is there:

```
         DATEADD(hour,datepart(tz,a.ClientTime),a.FacebookUpdateTime)
```

datepart(tz,a.ClientTime) return offset in minutes, so I change to

```
         DATEADD(minute,datepart(tz,a.ClientTime),a.FacebookUpdateTime)
```

2013-11-13 12:03:36.0000000 +02:00   datepart return 120.